hardhat ignition with script working with testnet but failed with localhost node network
when i run with testnet i get this
(https://i.sstatic.net/7ozQi2Se.png)
but when i run with localhost node i get this
(https://i.sstatic.net/vkpQq4o7.png)
and this is my node console when i using localhost node network
(https://i.sstatic.net/X6jS0scg.png)
this is my deploy.js code
const SimpleStorage = require('../ignition/modules/SimpleStorage');

async function main() {
  console.log('Deploying contract...');
  const { simpleStorage } = await hre.ignition.deploy(SimpleStorage);
  console.log(`SimpleStorage deployed to: ${await simpleStorage.getAddress()}`);

  const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve();
  const currentValueToString = currentValue.toString();

  console.log(`Current value is: ${currentValueToString}`);

  console.log('Updating value...');
  const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.store(4);
  await transactionResponse.wait();

  const updatedValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve();
  const updatedValueToString = updatedValue.toString();

  console.log(`Updated value is: ${updatedValueToString}`);
}

main().catch(console.error);


i already read this documentation but it not helping
https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/overview
